# Is there a way to keep track (Watch) the selected value of DropDownList in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

As titled, any solution in Visual Studio 2008?

I tried to add the `.SelectedValue`  into **Watch** during debug, but it gives me:

`The name 'SelectedValue' does not exist in the current context` Then there is a refresh icon with promp saying `Click this button to evaluate now`, but after clicking it, there is no value changes in the **Watch** window.

Comment: You don't want to watch `.SelectedValue` but `YourDropDownList.SelectedValue`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ah, that's why I did wrong.... It work now. +1

Comment: Shall i really add this as solution or do you want to delete this question?

Comment: You can add this as solution, I will mark it as solution when you added, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to watch `.SelectedValue` but `YourDropDownList.SelectedValue`.

Visual Studio will not automatically add missing parts since this would be a source of errors.